# How can I paginate the web pages of the following kind?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to paginate the pages of this site(http://www.geny-interim.com/offres/). The problem is I've used css selector to go through each page by using this code

```
next_page_url=response.css('a.page:nth-child(4)::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url)
```

But doing this will only paginate to two pages and then css selector not working as expected. I tried to use this also:

```
response.xpath('//*[contains(text(), "›")]/@href/text()').extract_first()
```

but this is also producing value error. Any help would be upvoted.

Comment: What do you mean all pages? You mean crawling the website or just finding all the job listings that are posted on the page?

Comment: I mean visiting to each page(paginating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with this XPath expression

```
//*[contains(text(), "›")]/@href/text()
```

because `href` attribute doesn't have a `text()` property.

Here's a working spider you can adapt to your needs:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class GenyInterimSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'geny-interim'
    start_urls = ['http://www.geny-interim.com/offres/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for offer in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"featured-box")]'):
            yield {
                'title': offer.xpath('.//h3/a/text()').extract_first()
            }
        next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[@class="page" and contains(.,"›")]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url), callback=self.parse)
```